# algorithm : given an array find i,j so that i<j & max(A[j]-A[i])

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, indexing, max

The algorithm must get array A[1,,,,n]representing the price of the share at N different times during the trading day .
What was the best time to buy a given stock and what was the best time to sell it?
I think I have to sort the array in ascending order so for the selling point so expensive price and buy on cheap price, how to solve without sorting if possible?

Comment: Just scan array, keeping current minimum and the best difference

Comment: the algorithm that i want  should be o(n^2) , your idea is not

Comment: This algorithm (same as marvel308 wrote in reverse direction) is better. It is linear. Quadratic complexity is for brute-force approach - checking of all pairs with j>i

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

1. Just loop from the last idx to the 0'th index
2. At every idx update the max value occurred until that point
3. if you buy the stock at that moment, you would want to sell at the max element which occurred after that. That would be the max element we have stored
4. For every step calculate the value of max - A[i]. The maximum of these would be your solution

Comment: if i sort it in ascending order .the i is the time of  buy cuz A[I]=cheap price &A[j]=expensive price , so just print i & j  after sorting ? correct ?

Comment: I am assuming A[] has element in order of the time of the price.

Comment: okay ' you say that the sorting not help solving the problem ?

Comment: yes i am not using sorting just the initial array

Comment: the algorithm that i want  should be o(n^2) , your idea is not

Comment: my algorithm is O(n). isn't that better ?

Comment: yes  but  i need one in worst case o(n^2) ?

Comment: if i use sorting , it wiil solve the problem ?

Comment: If you compare all A[i] with A[j] where j > i. in 2 loops. That woud be O(n^2)

Comment: the idea of sort then print index cant leaves me , can u please write that two ideas into a code  c\c++ or pseducode /